# Issues with a recursive function when trying to create a BST using Pseudoclassical Inheritance

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

So I'm trying to create a Binary Search Tree using Pseudoclassical inheritance. It accepts an array, sorts it, uses the middle value as the starting point, and inserts the remaining values from the array into the BST. I guess I'm trying my best to utilize functional programming (correct me if I'm wrong please) by using reuseable methods and also because a BST insert method needs to be recursive.

I've pointed out where the code errors out. I believe it takes 3 as the initial value, I also believe 1 (the next value in the array) successfully gets inserted, but I believe the number 2 is where the error occurs when it says that "TypeError: this.left.insert is not a function". Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Why won't the insert method call itself for this.left?

```
    var NoDuplicatesBST = function(array) {
      var tempArr = arguments[0].sort(function(a, b) {
        return a-b;
      });
      var middle = Math.floor(((tempArr.length - 1) / 2));
      var sliced = tempArr.splice(middle, 1);

      this.createBST(sliced[0]);

      // now insert the rest of tempArr into the BST
      for (var i = 0; i < tempArr.length; i++) {
        this.insert(tempArr[i]);
      }
    };

    NoDuplicatesBST.prototype.createBST = function(number) {
      this.value = number;
      this.left = null;
      this.right = null;
    };

    NoDuplicatesBST.prototype.insert = function(number) {
      if (number < this.value) {
        if (this.left === null) {
          this.left = new this.createBST(number);
        } else {
// ------------CODE BELOW DOES NOT WORK!, LINED 77 ALSO PROBABLY. TypeError: this.left.insert is not a function----------------------
          this.left.insert(number);
        }
      } else if (number > this.value) {
        if (this.right === null) {
          this.right = new this.createBST(number);
        } else {
          this.right.insert(number);
        }
      } else {
        // Do nothing
      }
    };

    var testBST = new NoDuplicatesBST([2,3,4,5,1]);

    console.log("The testBST:", testBST);
```

Comment: You use `this.createBST(number)` as a constructor, and that's not a constructor, create a separate class for your nodes

Answer (score 0):

That's not written in functional way, take a look and try to go thru this tutorial to learn more about functional programming in JS: http://reactivex.io/learnrx/

And to the original question why you see the `"TypeError: this.left.insert is not a function"`. Check my comments in your code:

```js
var NoDuplicatesBST = function(arr) {
  var middle, left = [], center, right = [];
  if (!Array.isArray(arr) || arr.length == 0) {
    return this;
  }
  if (arr.length == 1) {
    center = arr[0];
  } else {
    middle = Math.floor((arr.length / 2));
    center = arr[middle];
    left = arr.slice(0, middle);
    right = arr.slice(middle + 1, arr.length);
    console.log('left:', left);
    console.log('middle:', center);
    console.log('right:', right);
  }

  this.createBST(center);

  // now insert left and right parts to BST
  if (left.length > 0) {
    this.insert(left);
  }
  if (right.length > 0) {
    this.insert(right);
  }
};

NoDuplicatesBST.prototype.createBST = function(number) {
  this.value = number;
  this.left = null;
  this.right = null;
};

NoDuplicatesBST.prototype.insert = function(arr) {
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    //array is sorted and we took the middle element, so we can compare just the first element
    if (arr[0] < this.value) {
      /** Here you use createBST as a constructor, it creates a new element,
      with left and right values, but you break the prototypal inheritance chain,
      that's why you don't have access to the insert function */
      // this.left = new this.createBST(number);
      // it's better to pass the part of the array to build the tree further
      this.left = new NoDuplicatesBST(arr);
    } else {
      this.right = new NoDuplicatesBST(arr); //the same as above
    }
  }
};

var arr = [2, 3, 4, 5, 1];
var tempArr = arr.reduce(function (noDuplicatesArr, current) { //remove duplicates
  if (noDuplicatesArr.indexOf(current) === -1) {
    noDuplicatesArr.push(current);
  }

  return noDuplicatesArr;
}, []).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
var testBST = new NoDuplicatesBST(tempArr);
console.log("The testBST:", testBST);
```

For prototypal chain inheritance check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

BTW. I changed your code to accept arrays instead of numbers, now that will build a BST

Comment: If you console.log(this) right after this.left = new this.createBST(number), it looks like this:

{ value: 3,
  left: { value: 1, left: null, right: null },
  right: null }

Isn't that a BST?

Comment: @JeffYoo Please read my answer once again, I didn't say that is or isn't a BST, you create your node with `new this.createBST` which means you don't have access to `insert` method. You broke the prototypal inheritance chain there. What JS returns from `new this.createBST` isn't instance of NoDuplicatesBST class.

Comment: Is there a way I can fix this then?

Comment: @JeffYoo Yes, you need to refactor your code a little bit. I'll update my answer in a minute